# What is the fastest way to retrieve 10,000 records from SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, .net-core, aws-lambda

I am converting an old .NET core application to an AWS lambda function. The current code first hits the SQL server and gets a list of records. Then the code does a "foreach" loop and then performs 8 sql queries to get extra data for the current record.

The function needs to retrieve about 5,000 records and has nine subqueries; each subquery has multiple table joins.

I need this operation to finish in about 10 minutes but I am  not sure how to get that kind of speed. I am using a cursor right now and it is too slow. My code with 1 subquery is shown below.
What is the fastest way to retrieve this many records with nine subqueries?

```
-- declare variables used in cursor
    DECLARE @CUS_ID_SEQ VARCHAR(128);

-- declare cursor
DECLARE cursor_all_Agents CURSOR FOR
SELECT DISTINCT [CUS_ID_SEQ] 
FROM T_Customer C 

INNER JOIN T_State S_CUS ON S_CUS.STA_ID_SEQ=C.CUS_STA_ID_SEQ_FK 
INNER JOIN T_Location L ON L.LOC_CUS_ID_SEQ_FK=C.CUS_ID_SEQ 
INNER JOIN T_State S_Loc ON S_Loc.STA_ID_SEQ=L.LOC_STA_ID_SEQ_FK 
INNER JOIN T_Customer_Address CA on CA.CUAD_CUS_ID_SEQ_FK=C.CUS_ID_SEQ 
INNER JOIN T_Address A ON A.ADD_ID_SEQ = CA.CUAD_ADD_ID_SEQ_FK 
INNER JOIN T_State S ON S.STA_ID_SEQ = A.ADD_STA_ID_SEQ_FK 
INNER JOIN T_Contract CT ON CT.CTR_ID_SEQ = C.CUS_CTR_ID_SEQ_FK 
INNER JOIN T_Customer_Status CS ON CS.CSTA_ID_SEQ = C.CUS_CSTA_ID_SEQ_FK 
LEFT JOIN T_Customer_Affiliation CAFF ON CAFF.CAFF_CUS_ID_SEQ_FK=C.CUS_ID_SEQ 
LEFT JOIN T_Affiliation AF ON AF.AFF_ID_SEQ=CAFF.CAFF_AFF_ID_SEQ_FK 
LEFT JOIN T_Customer_Cancellation_Detail CCD ON CCD.CCAN_CUS_ID_SEQ_FK=C.CUS_ID_SEQ 
LEFT JOIN T_Cancellation_Reason CR ON CR.CNR_ID_SEQ=CCD.CCAN_CNR_ID_SEQ_FK 
LEFT JOIN T_Cancellation_Type CANT ON CANT.CNT_ID_SEQ=CCD.CCAN_CNT_ID_SEQ_FK 

WHERE (C.CUS_Number IS NOT NULL AND LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(C.CUS_Number))) > 0) 
            AND (L.LOC_Number IS NOT NULL AND LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(L.LOC_Number))) > 0) 
            AND (C.CUS_Name NOT LIKE '%TEST%') 
            AND ((CCD.CCAN_New_Date > '2010-01-01') OR (CCD.CCAN_New_Date IS NULL)) 
        AND CTR_Code NOT IN ('01', '05', '06', '07', '08', '10', '17', '13', '14')  
-- open cursor
OPEN cursor_all_Agents;

-- loop through a cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_all_Agents INTO @CUS_ID_SEQ;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN

    PRINT CONCAT('Cus_SEQ_Id id: ', @CUS_ID_SEQ);
    SELECT DISTINCT [CUS_ID_SEQ], [CUS_Name], [CUS_Number], [CUS_Email], [CUS_Website], [CUS_Primaryphone], [CUS_Secondaryphone], [CUS_TaxId], [CUS_Appointment_Date], [CUS_TL_Volume], [CUS_PL_Volume], [CUS_CL_Volume], [CUS_Vision_Statement], [CUS_Vision_Update_Dt], [CUS_Log], [CUS_SEG_ID_SEQ_FK], [CUS_CSTA_ID_SEQ_FK], [CUS_CTR_ID_SEQ_FK], [CUS_REG_ID_SEQ_FK], [CUS_TER_ID_SEQ_FK], [CUS_STA_ID_SEQ_FK], [CUS_Tax_Or_SSN], [CUS_Sort_Name], [CUS_Single_Location_Indicator], [CUS_Comp_PL_Volume], [CUS_Comp_CL_Volume], [CUS_Comp_TL_Volume], [CUS_Comp_Bonds_Volume], [CUS_Affiliation_Number], [CTR_ID_SEQ], [CTR_Code], [CTR_Name], [CSTA_ID_SEQ], [CSTA_Status], [CSTA_Desc], AF.AFF_Code, AF.AFF_Name, AF.AFF_Desc 
    FROM T_Customer C 

INNER JOIN T_State S_CUS ON S_CUS.STA_ID_SEQ=C.CUS_STA_ID_SEQ_FK 
INNER JOIN T_Location L ON L.LOC_CUS_ID_SEQ_FK=C.CUS_ID_SEQ 
INNER JOIN T_State S_Loc ON S_Loc.STA_ID_SEQ=L.LOC_STA_ID_SEQ_FK 
INNER JOIN T_Customer_Address CA on CA.CUAD_CUS_ID_SEQ_FK=C.CUS_ID_SEQ 
INNER JOIN T_Address A ON A.ADD_ID_SEQ = CA.CUAD_ADD_ID_SEQ_FK 
INNER JOIN T_State S ON S.STA_ID_SEQ = A.ADD_STA_ID_SEQ_FK 
INNER JOIN T_Contract CT ON CT.CTR_ID_SEQ = C.CUS_CTR_ID_SEQ_FK 
INNER JOIN T_Customer_Status CS ON CS.CSTA_ID_SEQ = C.CUS_CSTA_ID_SEQ_FK 
LEFT JOIN T_Customer_Affiliation CAFF ON CAFF.CAFF_CUS_ID_SEQ_FK=C.CUS_ID_SEQ
LEFT JOIN T_Affiliation AF ON AF.AFF_ID_SEQ=CAFF.CAFF_AFF_ID_SEQ_FK 
LEFT JOIN T_Customer_Cancellation_Detail CCD ON CCD.CCAN_CUS_ID_SEQ_FK=C.CUS_ID_SEQ 
LEFT JOIN T_Cancellation_Reason CR ON CR.CNR_ID_SEQ=CCD.CCAN_CNR_ID_SEQ_FK 
LEFT JOIN T_Cancellation_Type CANT ON CANT.CNT_ID_SEQ=CCD.CCAN_CNT_ID_SEQ_FK 

WHERE C.CUS_ID_SEQ=@CUS_ID_SEQ

FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_all_Agents INTO @CUS_ID_SEQ;
END;

-- close and deallocate cursor
CLOSE cursor_all_Agents;
DEALLOCATE cursor_all_Agents;
```

Comment: Likely best thing to do is going to be to just rewrite the whole thing from scratch but that is out of scope for someone to do that for you on a Q and A site. Cursors and loops should be avoided in favour of set based queries and it looks like there is a lot of repetition in the code that you posted

Comment: You can **definitely** combine this into one larger statement that the does whole job in one query, and when you do the database will be able to create an execution plan that can probably increase performance by an order of magnitude or even more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can see, the from clause and all of its associated joins are identical in both parts of your query. It also appears that many are not even referenced by either the where condition of in the final select list.

You effectively have:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CUS_ID_SEQ
FROM ...sources...
WHERE ...condition...
```

and then for each selected @CUS_ID_SEQ you are selecting:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ...select list...
FROM ...sources...
WHERE CUS_ID_SEQ = @CUS_ID_SEQ
```

You might be able combine the two into a single select:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ...select list...
FROM ...sources...
WHERE ...condition...
```

If for some reason, you want all of the records having CUS_ID_SEQ values where at least one CUS_ID_SEQ record satisfies your search condition, you might structure your query like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ...select list...
FROM ...sources...
WHERE CUS_ID_SEQ  IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT CUS_ID_SEQ 
    FROM ...sources...
    WHERE ...condition...
)
```

This uses a subselect to preselect all of the CUS_ID_SEQ values of interest. The outer select then retrieves all of the needed data for those selected CUS_ID_SEQ values.

Whichever way you go, I expect you can simplify the query by eliminating joins to unnecessary tables. From what I can see, your where condition only references:

- T_Customer
- T_Location
- T_Contract
- T_Customer_Cancellation_Detail

while your select list only needs the following:

- T_Customer
- T_Contract
- T_Customer_Status
- T_Customer_Affiliation
- T_Affiliation

Your use of DISTINCT may also be worth a review. To often, DISTINCT is used haphazardly where it is not needed or not appropriate. Sometimes it effectively hides underconstrained joins other query design issues.

Comment: I will build the SQL as you have listed here and report back on the performance results. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I gave TN the answer for having the clear  instructions. However, everyone contributed to it. With the cursor, the response time was 18 minutes for the SQL posted here. With the set-based suggestion, the execution time was less than 1 second:

```
SELECT DISTINCT   [CUS_ID_SEQ]
            , [CUS_Name]
            , [CUS_Number]
            , [CUS_Email]
            , [CUS_Website]
            , [CUS_Primaryphone]
            , [CUS_Secondaryphone]
            , [CUS_TaxId]
            , [CUS_Appointment_Date]
            , [CUS_TL_Volume]
            , [CUS_PL_Volume]
            , [CUS_CL_Volume]
            , [CUS_Vision_Statement]
            , [CUS_Vision_Update_Dt]
            , [CUS_Log]
            , [CUS_SEG_ID_SEQ_FK]
            , [CUS_CSTA_ID_SEQ_FK]
            , [CUS_CTR_ID_SEQ_FK]
            , [CUS_REG_ID_SEQ_FK]
            , [CUS_TER_ID_SEQ_FK]
            , [CUS_STA_ID_SEQ_FK]
            , [CUS_Tax_Or_SSN]
            , [CUS_Sort_Name]
            , [CUS_Single_Location_Indicator]
            , [CUS_Comp_PL_Volume]
            , [CUS_Comp_CL_Volume]
            , [CUS_Comp_TL_Volume]
            , [CUS_Comp_Bonds_Volume]
            , [CUS_Affiliation_Number]
            , [CTR_ID_SEQ]
            , [CTR_Code]
            , [CTR_Name]
            , [CSTA_ID_SEQ]
            , [CSTA_Status]
            , [CSTA_Desc]
            , AF.AFF_Code
            , AF.AFF_Name
            , AF.AFF_Desc 
FROM T_Customer C 

INNER JOIN T_Contract CT ON CT.CTR_ID_SEQ = C.CUS_CTR_ID_SEQ_FK 
INNER JOIN T_Customer_Status CS ON CS.CSTA_ID_SEQ = C.CUS_CSTA_ID_SEQ_FK 
LEFT JOIN T_Customer_Affiliation CAFF ON CAFF.CAFF_CUS_ID_SEQ_FK=C.CUS_ID_SEQ
LEFT JOIN T_Affiliation AF ON AF.AFF_ID_SEQ=CAFF.CAFF_AFF_ID_SEQ_FK 

WHERE C.CUS_ID_SEQ IN
(
SELECT DISTINCT [CUS_ID_SEQ] 
FROM T_Customer C 

INNER JOIN T_State S_CUS ON S_CUS.STA_ID_SEQ=C.CUS_STA_ID_SEQ_FK 
INNER JOIN T_Location L ON L.LOC_CUS_ID_SEQ_FK=C.CUS_ID_SEQ 
INNER JOIN T_State S_Loc ON S_Loc.STA_ID_SEQ=L.LOC_STA_ID_SEQ_FK 
INNER JOIN T_Customer_Address CA on CA.CUAD_CUS_ID_SEQ_FK=C.CUS_ID_SEQ 
INNER JOIN T_Address A ON A.ADD_ID_SEQ = CA.CUAD_ADD_ID_SEQ_FK 
INNER JOIN T_State S ON S.STA_ID_SEQ = A.ADD_STA_ID_SEQ_FK 
INNER JOIN T_Contract CT ON CT.CTR_ID_SEQ = C.CUS_CTR_ID_SEQ_FK 
INNER JOIN T_Customer_Status CS ON CS.CSTA_ID_SEQ = C.CUS_CSTA_ID_SEQ_FK 
LEFT JOIN T_Customer_Affiliation CAFF ON CAFF.CAFF_CUS_ID_SEQ_FK=C.CUS_ID_SEQ 
LEFT JOIN T_Affiliation AF ON AF.AFF_ID_SEQ=CAFF.CAFF_AFF_ID_SEQ_FK 
LEFT JOIN T_Customer_Cancellation_Detail CCD ON CCD.CCAN_CUS_ID_SEQ_FK=C.CUS_ID_SEQ 
LEFT JOIN T_Cancellation_Reason CR ON CR.CNR_ID_SEQ=CCD.CCAN_CNR_ID_SEQ_FK 
LEFT JOIN T_Cancellation_Type CANT ON CANT.CNT_ID_SEQ=CCD.CCAN_CNT_ID_SEQ_FK 

WHERE (C.CUS_Number IS NOT NULL AND LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(C.CUS_Number))) > 0) 
            AND (L.LOC_Number IS NOT NULL AND LEN(LTRIM(RTRIM(L.LOC_Number))) > 0) 
            AND (C.CUS_Name NOT LIKE '%TEST%') 
            AND ((CCD.CCAN_New_Date > '2010-01-01') OR (CCD.CCAN_New_Date IS NULL)) 
        AND CTR_Code NOT IN ('01', '05', '06', '07', '08', '10', '17', '13', '14')
```

)

Answer (score 0):

If you're allowed to change the schema I'd suggest checking the fields you join on and fields in where clause are indexed where appropriate .

As a rule of thumb you can speed up queries by indexing fields you join and filter on. The indexes that will make the most difference are on the fields in tables with the most rows. There is however a cost to indexing fields and so just because you can index a field it doesn't mean that you should. In the main adding indexes will slow down insertions and give the database server more work to do maintaining the indexes.

Your first port of call should be to optimise the query itself. That means understanding how it's working and removing unnecessary and expensive operations like joins,filters and subqueries where you can. User TN has gone into the details here so I wont.

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply. I am not a SQL person so I don't know what to request of our DBAs. Based on what i have so far can you tell me which columns should be indexed?

Comment: Get them to look for indexes on All the fields in your inner join, left join and where clauses. Of those the fields in the tables with most rows are most important to  index  to  speed up query if you  don't want to index them all.

Comment: I plan to try TN's changes today. I am also going to get the appropriate columns indexed.  Thanks